Overloading wirewound resistors
I need to add some wirewound resistor in series with a voltmeter to make it high range. I am converting the voltmeter from 300 V FSD to 900 V FSD.
As per my calculation the wattage should be 20 W, but I am getting only 10 W resistors in market.
So my question is if I use the 10 W resistors in place of 20 W resistor, can I run it for a short duration?
If yes how much duration will be safe to run them?
If I place a cooling FAN directly over the resistor will it help to extend the operating time?




Please be careful!  You can buy high voltage probes for exactly this sort of use.  They don't just contain a big resistor.  There is more to the design than that.  For some I have looked at the resistors are specially made very long and housed in an appropriately shaped and rated holder to prevent current flashing over or breaking through (thereby avoiding serious injury or death).

total 20200 ohm. i am putting 2 10k and 2 100 ohm resistor in series

Yes adding more resistors to make an equivalent resistor of desired wattage is possible, but that will make the unit bulky and cost will be 4 times. I can do that too, but I am just wandering how about running them for few seconds only to do the measurement and then let them cool down for 30 min before taking another measurement.

What is the input resistance of your voltmeter? A digital voltmeter usually has an input resistance of 10 megohms while analog meters are usually 20 kilohms per volt.  In either case, the series resistor should not be dissipating anywhere near 20 watts. Can you provide your calculations?

Are the resistors rated for 900 V? Please draw a schematic of your setup.

In the mid 20th century, a cheap voltmeter used a meter movement that had a 1 mA full scale, or 1000Ω/V. So, a 20kΩ resistor would yield a full scale of 20V. For 900V full scale you'd need 900kΩ. So, what are you using for a voltmeter that's inferior to ancient technology?

@JohnDoty "ancient"? Hey, now.  But, yes, ~45mA seems like an awful lot of current. Even rugged meter movements are usually in the 1mA range.

@Barry Its a analog voltmeter.  Voltmeter resistance is 10.1 K. FSD 300V. Current at FSD 0.0297A. Series resistance required 20.202K. Voltage drop across series resistor 600V. Power dissipation of series resistor 17.82W

I have updated my post with picture of my meter and calculation page from my notebook. Check the calculation if I am doing it wrong.

@winny I have shared the pictures in my post . Kindly check. There will be multiple wire-wound resistor and no resistor will have full 900 v across it. So it can withstand voltage.

Where does your voltmeter resistance figure come from? Is that measured, calculated, did you open it up and read component labels--?

you can substitute 4 identical resistors for one resistor to quadruple the heat dissipation/handling: 2p2s = 1.

Putting 20 W 100 ohm resistors in series is overkill, both from power rating and tolerance perspective. What will they bring to the party which the 20 kohm ones aren't already?

@TimWilliams I measured the resistance.

@winny Ok i did not calculate the power individually to every resistor. I need to do that. Thanks for pointing out

Good. Now, why do you need 20200 ohm and not just 20 kohm? Your resistors are probably 10 % accuracy anyway.

@winny OK your point is valid. What i plan to do now is to add a 1W 500 ohm variable in place of two 100 ohm resistor as their power consumption is 0.09 W actually. This variable resistor can help me fine tune the meter.

What's the voltage rating of your 20k resistors? Each will have about 300 V across it, exceeding the voltage specification of common grade resistors.

these are 10W rated wirewound resistor and will be able to handle 300 v easily.

@winny Yes I need to calculate the resistor power for every individual resistor. And I can see it will not cross 10W for each resistor. So within safe limit.

That didn’t answer my question. What’s the resistor tolerance?

@winny All resistor i am using have 5% tolerance

Then your added 200 ohm will disappear in the +-1000 ohm tolerance of your 20 kohm. If it’s a one-off, measure them individually and cherry pick to get to the desired value.

Check the datasheet.
A common rating on resistors is a five-second overload at some multiple of rated power (usually 5x).  Satisfactory performance is usually gauged by resistance being within tolerance after the overload, and perhaps other factors like discoloration or dielectric strength of coating/casing.  Sometimes the duration is shorter, or the multiplier is higher or lower, depending on type and size.
The spec probably comes from IEC 60115, though I couldn't tell you which part as these standards are largely only a concern for manufacturers; mostly as end-users we simply see what's in the datasheet.  On the upside, datasheets tend to be pretty coherent about providing these specs, a consequence of such standardization.
I wouldn't expect much lifetime in a repetitive condition.  Welded type resistors will likely fare better than otherwise (swaged?), but repetitive thermal stress and excessive temperature will eventually kill anything.
Not to mention, the high operating temperature exacerbates drift (temperature coefficient).  Even low-tempco types, I think, won't remain low over such a wide temperature swing.  And yes I mean to the point of, producing enough error that would be noticeable on an analog movement.
Much better to use an appropriate rating in the first place.

Ok what I understand that i can overload a wirewound resistor for say 5x times for a short duration for limited number time. Eventually it will wareout. In my application it will be used once in a while, even If i measure the voltage once in a month, then I can expect it to last at least 1 year. Also I am not loading it 5x times but 2x times approx and also it takes 2-3 seconds for me to see the voltage correctly. I can make a safe guess, that It will last for 2-3 year @ once in a month use or am i making overestimation ?

You would have to ask the manufacturer for life stats, maybe it's a few events, maybe it lasts basically forever, who knows. But yes, with that kind of operation, a part with these specifications will likely survive at least a few cycles.

Two ten watt resistors, in series or  parallel, can handle 20 W
easily.   A metering problem with high voltage might indicate that
a different technology would be preferable; there are electrostatic
voltmeters that have no resistor power losses at all.

yes so i can operate the instrument. i needed to calculate the resistors individually.

Resistors can generally be run briefly at a higher power than their continuous rating. However, most resistors are not specified for that type of operation, so it's not advised.
Film type resistors have a very tiny heat-generating part, and a large mass support body. Under pulse loading, the film heats rapidly before it can conduct heat away to the heavy body. This means their short pulse performance is not much better than their continuous rating. The long pulse performance, several seconds to take a voltage reading, might be better as the heat can conduct away from the film.
Bulk type resistors, for instance wirewound, heat uniformly a large mass of wire, so have much higher pulse handling capability. Some wirewound resistors even have pulse ratings in their specifications.
Frame challenge - dissipating a total of 30 watts to measure 900 V sounds somewhat excessive. I hope there's a good reason you're using such an insensitive voltmeter.
Resistors have a voltage rating. Generic resistors rarely have a rating exceeding one or two hundred volts. If you use a single resistor, it should have an adequate voltage rating, it will probably found in the 'high voltage' section of the catalogue. If you make a series connection between multiple resistors of the same value, you can add the voltage ratings, and the power ratings.

I cannot find any ready made voltmeter that can measure 1000V directly. Then I found this meter in a 2nd sale in good deal. I was attracted to its BIG display. This is only reason I have it. I did not know that it will act like a dummy load.

You can run the resistor above its DC rating if the datasheet provides information saying you can do it.
Typically, this would be a graph, a table, or a statement specifying various combinations of power levels and time durations.
If the datasheet doesn't you can, it may or may not work.  You could ask the manufacturer for data saying one way or the other.  But if they won't give it then it's sort of a gamble at that point.
If you are just building one of something you could always just buy a few of the resistors and extensively test them until they fail.  If they all work at power levels well above your intended use case for a long time, then you could probably use one.
If you are building many copies, you would have to test many resistors to characterize them.  But even if you did that, there would be nothing stopping the manufacturer from making changes that invalidate your test, yet still match the original datasheet.  So, this wouldn't be advised for a mass-produced product unless you could get some guarantee from the manufacturer saying they won't change anything.

I am making for my use only and that too very occasionally to check health of my High voltage RF transmitter PSU
